# Is this extension of the projectively extended real line, consistent?

Tags: set-theory, theories-of-arithmetic

This posting has been Edited. The edited material shall be noted.

[The projectively extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line)  $\hat {\mathbb R}= \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ is one system which allows division by zero! Yet it has many [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line#Arithmetic_operations_that_are_left_undefined) arithmetic operations.

If we weaken the requirement of the operators being binary *functions* to being ternary ***relations***, and so can relate many values to the same arguments; then those undefined operations can be settled in the sense of getting some kind of closure under them.

I'll adopt the notation "$a * b \to c$" to mean: the operator $*$ is a ternary relation that sends the ordered pair $(a,b)$ to $c$; for convience, it can be read as: $c$ is a result of $a * b$.

Now we may coin a closure notion over $\hat {\mathbb R}$ under an operator $*$ as:

$ \hat {\mathbb R} \text { closed under } * \iff \forall x,y \in \hat{\mathbb R} \exists z \in \hat {\mathbb R}: x * y \to z$

I'll revert to the functional expression (i.e. $x * y = z$) only when $z$ is unique per $(x,y)$

The following is a possible extension:

$\infty + \infty = \infty \\ \infty - \infty \to r \\ \infty \times 0 \to r \\ 0 \times \infty \to r \\ \infty / \infty \to r \\ 0 /0 \to r$

Where $r$ is any element of $\hat{\mathbb R}$.

> [EDIT]: the above was the original suggestion, which was motivated by defining subtraction and division as the reciprocal relation of addition and multiplication respectively, i.e.:

> $a - b \to c \iff c + b \to a \\ a / b \to c \iff c \times b \to a$

> But, ($\infty + \infty \to \infty$) doesn't conform to that! We have $r - \infty = \infty$ so this results in $\infty + \infty 
> \to r$, so this  to be corrected to ($\infty + \infty \to r$); for all $r \in \hat{\mathbb R}$.

> Additional motivation is to have multiplication by zero be equivalent with self subtraction.

Accordingly $\hat{\mathbb R}$ would be closed under operators "$+,-,\times, /$" in the sense defined here.

Perhaps a similar move can be done for the Riemanian sphere $\mathbb C^*$, to gain closure under more operators.

> Is this system consistent relative to $\sf ZFC$? More specifically, what are the particulars of what could be viewed to constitute somehwat natural interpretation of this system in $\sf ZFC$?

Comment: Google "nonstandard analysis."

Comment: @MonroeEskew This has nothing to do with nonstandard analysis as far as I can tell.

Comment: The consistency question doesn't really make any sense - obviously since it has a model (that's how you're describing it!), all the rules of your system are consistent. You may be interested in the notion of **hyperstructures** and in particular **hyper*fields*** - see e.g. [this blog post by Matt Baker](https://mattbaker.blog/2016/03/10/matroids-over-hyperfields-part-i/).

Comment: @NoahSchweber  I guess you're right. My thought was more like, why worry about making sense of these things when we have non-archimedean fields to look at?

Comment: So how do you make sense of $\infty + \infty - \infty \to \infty + r \to \infty \to  \infty - \infty \to r$?

Comment: @MonroeEskew Since operations are multivalued, rrows aren't reversible here. So indeed we have $\infty+\infty-\infty\rightarrow\infty$ and $\infty+\infty-\infty\rightarrow r$, but that doesn't mean that $\infty\rightarrow r$. (Precisely: the $\infty\rightarrow\infty-\infty$ step in your comment breaks down.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I should say Thanks for directing me to Matt Baker's blog! That is at the heart of what I'm thinking of!

Comment: @NoahSchweber, the point that made me ask about consistency is actually $\infty + \infty = \infty$ and $\infty - \infty \to r$, I need to visualize this in some fragment of ZFC, I should confess that I can find some fragment with two distinct signed infinities with different consequences than those here, i.e. we extend the affinely extended real line, and as I said the results are different but I think I can find a model for it, but this projective one I need to figure it out. The consistency question is about the details of interpretation of these operations in ZFC.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, the step $\infty \to \infty - \infty$ is not well formed here, possibly you mean $\infty \pm r \to \infty - \infty$, but this is not among the rules here, and I don't think it's derivable here. So, as Noah mentioned this step breaks down.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I meant $(\infty +\infty) -\infty \to \infty -\infty$. So one expression “arrows” every element.

Comment: @MonroeEskew the expressions $(\infty + \infty) - \infty$ , $\infty + (\infty - \infty)$ do not necessary yield the same values. The first is multivalued (arrows every element of $\hat{\mathbb R}$), but the second is mono-valued. So they are not the same expressions.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar You really want to give up associativity? I thought this was trying to make sense of naive analysis arguments.  What is the motivation?

Comment: @MonroeEskew, at $\infty$ and regarding opposing operators, sadly yes. I'm thinking of the simplest system that extends the reals and in which division by zero is definable

Comment: If all you want is some formal system in which an operation is defined, then you can just extend the usual operations on the reals by defining $r/0 = 0$ for all $r$.  But this seems unsatisfying, right?

Comment: @MonroeEskew, well I need division to retain some of meanings of the usual division, we don't need the system to have very remote features, if $r/0=0$ then division is not the converse relation of multiplication, and so in this sense it seems distant from the usual intuition associated with division, which is indeed, as you said, unsatisfactory.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, in particular, this won't suit the purpose of this posting, namely to extend the projectively extended real line, here this leads to $\infty = 0$ which is clearly inconsistent.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article you linked, the structure $\hat{\mathbb R}$ is supposed to satisfy associativity of addition.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, yes, true, these *equalities* work here as well, the word *defined* in the conditions written correspond to mono-valuation here. This fails once this condition is not met.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar If we are dealing with multi-valued relations, it's not inconsistent to stipulate $\infty \to 0$.  I'm not sure what the goals are.  The idea of the projective real line is that going to infinity in either direction wraps around, correct?  Maybe you could give some geometric motivation to these multi-valued relations you want to introduce?

Comment: @MonroeEskew, be careful, what you wrote is not an arrow expression, what you've written (in your earlier comment) is $r/0 = 0$ this is an *equation*, this *is* straighforwardly inconsistent with the projectively extended real line, since $\infty +1 = \infty$ and $0 +1 \neq 0$. If we write $r/0 \to 0$, then this might work given that $r/0$ is multivalued. That is another story. You don't want to give up on associativity of mixed addition subtraction expressions, if that is an axiom, then of course my method here fails.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, but anyway, the idea of the projective extension is that $1/0$ represents a single number, and so it is not multi-valued, and so it cannot equal $0$, it is the point on the other side, so it must be distinct from zero, even at initial intuitive level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an account on the particulars of an interpretation of the original system [before the edit] presented in this question in set theory.

First we define an extended kind of rationals to suit adding a rational that is higher than  all other rationals, the latter would correspond to $\infty$. The set of all those rationals shall be denoted by $\mathbb Q^*$

$\text {Define}: r \in \mathbb Q^* \iff  r \subseteq \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \land [\operatorname {image}(r) = \mathbb R \lor \operatorname {preimage}(r) = \mathbb R] \land \\\exists a,b \in \mathbb Z : r= \{\langle a \times x, b \times x \rangle \mid x \in \mathbb R \}$

In the above definition $r$ is meant to represent the rational number $a/b$ for integers $a,b$.

A strict smaller than relation $<$ can be defined on $\mathbb Q^*$ as:

$r < s \iff \\ r \neq s \land \exists  x  \exists a \, \exists b \,( a < b \land \langle a, x \rangle \in r \land \langle b, x \rangle \in s)$

As usual elements of $\mathbb Q^*$ strictly below $0/1$ are negatively signed, those above except $\infty$ are positively signed, while the rest (i.e.; $0, \infty$) are unsigned, this can also be captured in terms of sets as the signed rationals being those which have both their images and preimages being $\mathbb R$.

So we define: $\infty = \{ \langle x,0 \rangle \mid x \in \mathbb R \}$, i.e. the reciprocal of $0/1 = \{\langle 0,x\rangle \mid x \in \mathbb R \}$

**Addition** of any two extended rationals $r,s$ is given by:

$r + s =\{\langle a+b,c \rangle \mid \langle a,c \rangle \in r\land \langle b,c \rangle \in s\}$

This gives: $r + \infty = \infty + r= \infty$ for all $r \in \mathbb Q$

**Subtraction over** $\mathbb Q^*$:

$r - s  \to q \iff \\ q+s =  r \lor q= \{\langle a-b,c \rangle \mid \langle a,c \rangle \in r\land \langle b,c \rangle \in s\}  $

This gives: $r - \infty = \infty-r = \infty$, for all $r \neq \infty$

and $ \infty - \infty \to r $, forall $r \in \mathbb Q^*$.

**Multiplication over** $\mathbb Q^*$:

$r \neq 0, s \neq 0 \\  r \times s = \{\langle k \times x,a \rangle , \langle t \times h, m^2 \rangle   \mid (\langle t,m \rangle \in r [s] \land \langle h,m \rangle \in s [r]) \land  (\langle k,1 \rangle \in r [s] \land \langle x,a \rangle \in s [r]) \} $

Where: $(z \in r[s] \land u \in s[r])$, is short for: $(z \in r \land u \in s) \lor (z \in s \land u \in r)$

if $r =0 \lor s=0 \implies r \times s \to (r-r)+(s-s) $

So, we get: $r \times \infty = \infty \times r= \infty$, for all $r \neq 0$

and, $0 \times \infty \to r; \infty \times 0 \to r $, forall $r \in \mathbb Q^*$

Now, that we defined addition and multiplication of the extended rationals, we can define extended reals as Dedekind cuts over $\mathbb Q^*$

A Dedekind cut shall be defined here as a binary partition on $\mathbb Q^*$, with one block being an initial segment (i.e.; closed under $<$) of $\mathbb Q^*$ that is open upwardly.  So, for example $\{\mathbb Q^* \setminus \{\infty\}, \{\infty\}\}$ is a Dedekind cut, and it is taken to represent the real number that corresponds to the extended rational number $\infty$, and so it'll be denoted by "$[\infty]$". The elements of a Dedekind cut are to be termed *initial*, *terminal* abbreviated as *init,term*, the former is the one closed dowardly, the latter is the one closed upwardly.

We can define a total order $<$ on Dedekind cuts themselves, this is given by:

$K < L \iff \operatorname {init}(K) \subsetneq \operatorname {init}(L)$

That said, then clearly $[\infty]$ is strictly greater than all other cuts. Formally this is: $$ r \neq [\infty] \implies r < [\infty]$$, for every extended real $r$.

The set of extended reals to be designated by $\hat {\mathbb R}$

As a terminology if $S$ and $C$ are nonempty subsets of $\mathbb Q^*$, then:

$S \ * \ C = \{a \ * \ b \mid a \in S \land b \in C \} $

Where "$*$" is some arithmetic operator.

Define: $X=\{S,-\} \iff X=\{S, \mathbb Q^* \setminus S \}$

**Addition of extended reals:**

$K+L = \{ \operatorname {init}(K) + \operatorname {init}(L), - \} $

This yields: $r + [\infty] = [\infty]$, for all $r \in \hat{\mathbb R}$

**Subtraction of extended reals:**

$  K-L \to X \iff \\ X + L=K \lor \\K < [\infty] \land L=[\infty] \land X=[\infty]$

Another definition is:
$K-L \to X \iff \\ X + L=K \lor \\ X = \{\operatorname {init} (K) - \{x \in \operatorname {term}(L) \mid L \neq [\infty] \to x \neq \infty  \}, - \}$

This gives: $ r - [\infty]=  [\infty]-r = [\infty] $, for all $r \neq [\infty]$,

and: $[\infty] -[\infty] \to r $, for all $ r \in \hat {\mathbb R}$.

Define: $\operatorname {Comp} (S) = S \cup \{\operatorname {Inf}(S)\} $

$\operatorname {Comp}$ is read as the *completion* set of.

**Multiplication of extended reals:**

$K  > 0 \land L > 0: \\K \times L= \{\operatorname {Comp} (\operatorname {term}(K) \times \operatorname {term}(L)) , -\}$

$ K > 0 \land L < 0:  K \times L = 0 - (K \times (0 - L))$

$ K < 0 \land L < 0: K \times L = (0-K) \times (0-L)$

$ K = 0 \lor L = 0:\\ K \times L \to X \iff (K-K) + (L-L) \to X$

Accordingly: $r \times [\infty] = [\infty]$, if $r \neq 0$;

and: $0 \times [\infty] \to r, [\infty] \times 0 \to r $; for all $r \in \hat {\mathbb R}$

**Division of extended reals:**

$ K/L \to X \iff  X \times L \to K $

Yielding: $[\infty]/r = [\infty], r/[\infty]=0$, for all $r \neq [\infty] $;

and:  $r/ 0 = [\infty], [\infty]/[\infty] \to r, 0/0 \to r $, for all $r \in \hat{\mathbb R}$.

This would establish the interpretation of the projectively extended real line in $\sf ZFC$, and also provides an answer to the undetermined expressions mentioned in the Wikipedia page, along the lines mentioned in this question. So, it proves the consistency of this system.

Comment: As @NoahSchweber [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434794/is-this-extension-of-the-projectively-extended-real-line-consistent#comment1120010_434794), you start with a model of your theory, so of course your theory is consistent; and it seems that what is left to ask, which was discussed at some length in the comments, is for what this theory is interesting or useful.  So, given that the theory is already consistent, what is really being proven here?

Comment: @LSpice, I didn't start with a model of my theory, I never gave the details of the construction of any model of the purported theory as a set in $\sf ZFC$ in my question, I've just made a claim for extending the theory about projectively extending the real line with the expressions I've set; I didn't say I have a model of those, and even if there was an implicit suggestion of existence of such a model, I didn't show it, this answer proves the consistency of this theory by proving an interpretation of it in $\sf ZFC$. Of course the model would be $(\hat {\mathbb R}, =, +, -, \times, /)$